# Atribuir valor a um input específico

Tags: jquery, html5, dom

Bom dia pessoa,

Estou com dificuldade em realizar um código.

Tenho vários Inputs que são criados de maneira dinâmica. Preciso pegar o ID do elemento específico para fazer alteração do valor dele.

EX:
Tenho os seguintes campos: Dias, Faltas, Vacância, Licença, Licença Médica e Acidente de Trabalho.
O campo Dias tem um valor de 30, os demais campos podem variar dependendo do funcionário. A soma de todos os campos(Faltas, Vacância, Licença, Licença Médica e Acidente de Trabalho) não pode ultrapassar 30, além disso, assim que o usuário digitar algo nesses campos ele tem q atualizar imediatamente o campo Dias reduzindo seu valor.

Segue o código abaixo para melhor entendimento.

```
@foreach ($servidores as $i => $servidor)
<form id="formid{{$i++}}" role="form" method="get" action="/mapa_servidor/editMapaServidor/{{$servidor->id}}">
    <tr data-index="0" id="formulario{{$i}}" class="input-sm" {{$servidor->st_lancado == 'X'? $cor = "#38A8A2": $cor = "FFFFFF"}} style="background-color: {{$cor}}">
        <td class="text-left">
            <input type="text" class="nm_servidor" id="nm_servidor{{$i}}" name="nm_servidor[]" value="{{$servidor->nm_servidor}}" readonly>
            <input type="hidden" id="dt_referencia" name="dt_referencia" value="{{$servidor->dt_referencia}}" readonly>
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}" />
            <br>
        </td>
        <td class="text-left">
            <input type="text" class="nr_matricula" id="nr_matricula{{$i}}" name="nr_matricula[]" value="{{$servidor->nr_matricula}}" readonly>
        </td>
        <td class="text-left">
            <input type="text" class="cd_departamento" id="cd_departamento{{$i}}" name="cd_departamento[]" value="{{$servidor->cd_departamento}}" readonly>
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="total nr_dias" id="nr_dias{{$i}}" name="nr_dias[]" value="{{rtrim($servidor->nr_dias)}}" readonly>
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="calc nr_faltas" id="nr_faltas{{$i}}" name="nr_faltas[]" pattern="[0-9]+$" value="{{rtrim($servidor->nr_faltas)}}" {{$servidor->st_lancado == 'X'? 'readonly': '' }}>
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="calc nr_vacancia" id="nr_vacancia{{$i}}" name="nr_vacancia[]" pattern="[0-9]+$" value="{{rtrim($servidor->nr_vacancia)}}" {{$servidor->st_lancado == 'X'? 'readonly': '' }}>
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="calc nr_licenca" id="nr_licenca{{$i}}" name="nr_licenca[]" pattern="[0-9]+$" value="{{rtrim($servidor->nr_licenca)}}" {{$servidor->st_lancado == 'X'? 'readonly': '' }}>
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="calc nr_licenca_medica" id="nr_licenca_medica{{$i}}" name="nr_licenca_medica[]" pattern="[0-9]+$" value="{{rtrim($servidor->nr_licenca_medica)}}" {{$servidor->st_lancado == 'X'? 'readonly': '' }}>
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="calc nr_acidente_trabalho" id="nr_acidente_trabalho{{$i}}" name="nr_acidente_trabalho[]" pattern="[0-9]+$" value="{{rtrim($servidor->nr_acidente_trabalho)}}" {{$servidor->st_lancado == 'X'? 'readonly': '' }}>
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="nr_adicional_noturno" id="nr_adicional_noturno{{$i}}" name="nr_adicional_noturno[]" value="{{rtrim($servidor->nr_adicional_noturno)}}" {{$servidor->st_lancado == 'X'? 'readonly': '' }}>
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="nr_he_norm_diurno" id="nr_he_norm_diurno{{$i}}" name="nr_he_norm_diurno[]" value="{{rtrim($servidor->nr_he_norm_diurno)}}" {{$servidor->st_lancado == 'X'? 'readonly': '' }}>
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="nr_he_norm_noturno" id="nr_he_norm_noturno{{$i}}" name="nr_he_norm_noturno[]" value="{{rtrim($servidor->nr_he_norm_noturno)}}" {{$servidor->st_lancado == 'X'? 'readonly': '' }}>
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="nr_he_dom_diurno" id="nr_he_dom_diurno{{$i}}" name="nr_he_dom_diurno[]" value="{{rtrim($servidor->nr_he_dom_diurno)}}" {{$servidor->st_lancado == 'X'? 'readonly': '' }}>
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="nr_he_dom_noturno" id="nr_he_dom_noturno{{$i}}" name="nr_he_dom_noturno[]" value="{{rtrim($servidor->nr_he_dom_noturno)}}" {{$servidor->st_lancado == 'X'? 'readonly': '' }}>
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="checkbox" class="st_grat_reuniao" id="st_grat_reuniao{{$i}}" name="st_grat_reuniao[]" {{($servidor->st_grat_reuniao) == 'X'? 'checked': '' }} {{$servidor->st_lancado == 'X'? 'readonly': '' }}>
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="ds_observacao" id="ds_observacao{{$i}}" name="ds_observacao[]" value="{{rtrim($servidor->ds_observacao)}}" {{$servidor->st_lancado == 'X'? 'readonly': '' }}>
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="checkbox" class="st_lancado" id="st_lancado{{$i}}" name="st_lancado[]" {{$servidor->st_lancado == 'X'? 'checked': '' }} required>
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Salvar</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

@endforeach

Da maneira que fiz, ele está modificando todos os inputs de nome nr_dias. Em vez de modificar somente da linha que eu necessito. Sei que estou fazendo errado, mas não estou conseguindo pensar na solução.

```js
$(document).on("keyup", ".calc", function() {
  var sum = 0;

  $(".calc").each(function(){
   sum += +$(this).val();
  });
  if(sum > 30){
   $(".total").val(30);
   $(".calc").val('');
  }else{

   $(".total").val(30-sum);
  }
 });
```

Comment: Eu acho que o título da pergunta não condiz com o escopo da pergunta...

Comment: O problema tem que está na pergunta e você sabe que o problema não está em como pegar o id do elemento, porque você já sabe como o fazer.

Comment: Outro erro é que você colocou no título: javascript, mas colocou tag jquery, deixa confuso sobre quem vai responder...Devo responder em javascript ou jquery?

Comment: Estou falando isso porque vai lhe ajudar muito a conseguir algo por aqui. Eu também passei por isso, não desanime!

Comment: Lollipop sem problemas. Irei tomar mais cuidado da próxima vez. Alterei o título da pergunta e removi a tag javascript.

Comment: Não vejo problema em deixar a tag `javascript` desde que também tenha `jquery`. Você pode resolver apenas com a lógica do `javascript` sem nada de `jquery`, o problema poderia ser um `if` por exemplo  ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não precisa do ID, mas você precisa usar só os inputs da mesma linha.

No seu código, onde você referencia os elementos, aqui por exemplo:

```
$(".total").val(30-sum);
```

você precisa pegar a referência só da mesma linha, ou seja, a mesma `TR`, assim:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find(".total").val(30-sum);
```

O `this` pega a referência do `input` que está sendo alterado, o `closest('tr')` pega a referência da `TR` pai mais próxima, e finalmente usei o `find(".total")` para procurar os controles somente aninhados com a `TR`.

Isso deve ser feito para todas as referências. Veja o exemplo simplificado:

```js
$(document).on("keyup", ".calc", function() {
 var sum = 0;

 $(this).closest('tr').find(".calc").each(function(){
     sum += +$(this).val();
 });
 if(sum > 30){
     $(this).closest('tr').find(".total").val(30);
     $(this).closest('tr').find(".calc").val('');
 }else{
     $(this).closest('tr').find(".total").val(30-sum);
 }
});
```

```css
input {
  width: 50px
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <tr data-index="0" >
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="total nr_dias"  name="nr_dias[]" value="30" readonly>
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="calc nr_faltas"  name="nr_faltas[]">
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="calc nr_vacancia"  name="nr_vacancia[]">
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="calc nr_licenca"  name="nr_licenca[]" >
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="calc nr_licenca_medica"  name="nr_licenca_medica[]">
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="calc nr_acidente_trabalho"  name="nr_acidente_trabalho[]" >
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr data-index="1" >
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="total nr_dias"  name="nr_dias[]" value="30" readonly>
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="calc nr_faltas"  name="nr_faltas[]">
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="calc nr_vacancia"  name="nr_vacancia[]">
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="calc nr_licenca"  name="nr_licenca[]" >
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="calc nr_licenca_medica"  name="nr_licenca_medica[]">
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="calc nr_acidente_trabalho"  name="nr_acidente_trabalho[]" >
        </td>
    </tr>


    <tr data-index="2" >
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="total nr_dias"  name="nr_dias[]" value="30" readonly>
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="calc nr_faltas"  name="nr_faltas[]">
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="calc nr_vacancia"  name="nr_vacancia[]">
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="calc nr_licenca"  name="nr_licenca[]" >
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="calc nr_licenca_medica"  name="nr_licenca_medica[]">
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="calc nr_acidente_trabalho"  name="nr_acidente_trabalho[]" >
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Ricardo Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Seu código resolveu meu problema. Agradeço sua atenção. Tenha um bom dia.

Answer (score -2):

```js
$(document).on("keyup", ".calc", function() {
 var sum = 0;

 $(this).closest('tr').find(".calc").each(function(){
     sum += +$(this).val();
 });
 if(sum > 30){
     $(this).closest('tr').find(".total").val(30);
     $(this).closest('tr').find(".calc").val('');
 }else{
     $(this).closest('tr').find(".total").val(30-sum);
 }
});
```

```css
input {
  width: 50px
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <tr data-index="0" >
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="total nr_dias"  name="nr_dias[]" value="30" readonly>
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="calc nr_faltas"  name="nr_faltas[]">
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="calc nr_vacancia"  name="nr_vacancia[]">
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="calc nr_licenca"  name="nr_licenca[]" >
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="calc nr_licenca_medica"  name="nr_licenca_medica[]">
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="calc nr_acidente_trabalho"  name="nr_acidente_trabalho[]" >
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr data-index="1" >
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="total nr_dias"  name="nr_dias[]" value="30" readonly>
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="calc nr_faltas"  name="nr_faltas[]">
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="calc nr_vacancia"  name="nr_vacancia[]">
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="calc nr_licenca"  name="nr_licenca[]" >
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="calc nr_licenca_medica"  name="nr_licenca_medica[]">
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="calc nr_acidente_trabalho"  name="nr_acidente_trabalho[]" >
        </td>
    </tr>


    <tr data-index="2" >
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="total nr_dias"  name="nr_dias[]" value="30" readonly>
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="calc nr_faltas"  name="nr_faltas[]">
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="calc nr_vacancia"  name="nr_vacancia[]">
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="calc nr_licenca"  name="nr_licenca[]" >
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="calc nr_licenca_medica"  name="nr_licenca_medica[]">
        </td>
        <td class="text-left" style="">
            <input type="text" class="calc nr_acidente_trabalho"  name="nr_acidente_trabalho[]" >
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```